# width property is not working in css3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

```css
.chat-box{
  width:50%;
  height:360px;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  border:1px solid grey;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mrgn_cnt">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 chat-box">
            <div class="whte_box"><!-- white box start-->
            </div>
            <!-- end of whitebox-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap framework. What I am trying to achieve is, width of 50% of class chat-box but width property is not working even if I add another property to class chat-box like `display:block;` still width property is not working.

I am expecting to work it as block level element, instead of it I got nothing is working except the background height border. I have tried everything and rechecked. I do not know what exactly is causing that problem?

Comment: maybe it override by col-sm-8

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because by using this bootstrap class `col-sm-8` , you are setting it's width to 66.66%, either use class `col-sm-6` instead of `col-sm-8`. or bring your `.chat-box` inside

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="chat-box">
       <!-- white box start-->
       <div class="white_box">
       </div>
       <!-- end of whitebox-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and then apply width property accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.chat-box{
    width:200px;
    height:360px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid grey;      
}
```

then remove `col-sm-8`

OR

add this:

```
.row{
    width:500px;     
}
```

then remove `col-sm-8`